# How to get value of dynamic input text using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My jQuery looks like -

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("[id^=SelectAssignThis-]").click(function(){
       var ProjectID = $("[id^=GetProjectID-]").val();
       var UserIntID = $("[id^=GetUserIntID-]").val();
       $.ajax( {
          type : 'GET',
          url:'test1.php',
          data : {ProjectID: ProjectID, UserIntID :UserIntID},
          success:function(data) {
             $('#ShowAjaxesult').html(data);
          }
       });
   });
});
</script>
```

My `php` code looks like -

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($QueryResult))
{
    $ProjectID                 = $row['ProjectID'];
    $Tiltle                    = $row['Title'];
    ?> <tr>
            <td><a href="#" id="SelectAssignThis-<?php echo $ProjectID; ?>">Assign</a></td>                    
            <td><input type="hidden" id="GetUserIntID-<?php echo $ProjectID; ?>" value="<?php echo $UserIntID; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" id="GetProjectID-<?php echo $ProjectID; ?>" value="<?php echo $ProjectID; ?>">
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $ProjectID; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Tiltle; ?></td>
       </tr><?php
};
```

Now `val ProjectID` in my jQuery is always returning the `ProjectID` corresponding to first occurrence of while loop. For eg- IF `while` loop occurs ten time and I click on the `<a>`  of fifth occurrence (with `id=SelectAssignThis-5`), I'm getting value of `ProjectID` corresponding to `<a>` of `id=SelectAssignThis-1`. I want to get the value of `ProjectID` correspond to `id=SelectAssignThis-5` when a click on 5th occurence of `<a>`, Similarly `id=SelectAssignThis-6` when I select 6th occurrence and so on. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val` method returns value of the first matched element. Use the `this` keyword:

```
var $td = $(this).closest('td').next();
var ProjectID = $td.find("[id^=GetProjectID-]").val();
var UserIntID = $td.find("[id^=GetUserIntID-]").val();
```

Suggestions:

- Add a className to the elements and use the class selector, attribute selectors are not efficient.
- Do not use StudlyCase identifiers for non-Constructors.
- You can also put the hidden inputs in the first cells and use the `siblings` method for selecting the target elements.

Comment: I tried above but now it's not returning any value. I also tried class   selector but still getting the same problem.

Comment: @user1968150 Sorry, I missed the `next` call.